# Why does a mocked method swallow exceptions?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, nmock2

**Current Implementation:**

```
void IFileManager.DeleteFile(
  string argFilename )
{
    throw new ArgumentException( "Specified filename was not found" );
}
```

**Unit Test**

```
Expect.Once.On( m_MockFileManager ).Method( "DeleteFile" );
....
....
```

The unit test passes, all green.  I expected the test to fail because an exception should have been thrown.  When I run this test without using a mocking framework, the exception is thrown and the test fails.

Why does the mocking framework swallow the exception?

Comment: What mocking/unit-testing framework?  Do you have some sort of `[ExpectedException]` attribute on the test method?

Comment: When you say "Current Implementation" what do you actually mean? Is that what you put in your Fake object, or is that the real implementation? With most mocking frameworks, your mocked method doesn't do anything until you tell it what to do, it's just an empty method.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to provide more code than that one line, but my guess is that you are mocking out the object that calls `DeleteFile` and it does not actually call the `DeleteFile` method. As long as the code calls that method, then you code will pass. Again, a fuller picture of your code will allow a better answer.

Comment: So if something goes wrong (an exception) from any of the method calls in my method under test (not DeleteFile as you pointed out), then I'm basically SOL?  For example, if I call 10 different methods inside my method under test, and just one of those 10 methods blow up, I won't know about it?

Comment: Well, if you are expecting DeleteFile followed by another call, then that other method should not be called as the exception would have short-circuited the method. I do not know nmock2 implementation, so this might be different

Comment: that's just it, all 10 methods are called even though one in the middle was suppose to throw an exception.  I can only guess that the mocking framework creates a new instance of the DeleteFile based on the interface with an empty body, hence it doesn't even use the same implementation as the actual code.

Comment: That would be my guess, you do not explicitly create a fake of DeleteFile?